# Testing on JWebUnit

Tags: servlets, testing, jwebunit

I am trying to do integration test on my servlets with the JWebUnit framework. All I've done is importing the two jar files needed (`jwebunitcore` and `jwebunit-htmlunit-plgin`) into my class path. Here is the code:

```
package com.ec.projectName.server;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import net.sourceforge.jwebunit.junit.JWebUnit;
import net.sourceforge.jwebunit.util.TestingEngineRegistry;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class ViewTest {

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        JWebUnit.setTestingEngineKey(TestingEngineRegistry.TESTING_ENGINE_HTMLUNIT);
        JWebUnit.setBaseUrl("http://localhost:8080/projectName");
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {

        JWebUnit.beginAt("View.html");
        JWebUnit.assertTitleEquals("View result");
        JWebUnit.assertFormPresent();
        JWebUnit.assertFormElementPresent("preferred_name");
        JWebUnit.assertFormElementPresent("zip_Code");
    }
}
```

Finally I run this as junit test and my servlet is running in the browser, but I am still getting an error as result!

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: If you are using Eclipse then you also need to configure your build path.